# How can I get the date but not time from NSDate

Tags: iphone, localization, formatting, nsdate

I need the date as a string but not the time and it has to be localized.

So for example USA should be *Sep 25 2009* but for New Zealand it would be *25 Sep 2009*.
I can get the date into a string by specifying the format "MMM dd YYYY" but It's not localized.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

```
[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                               dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
                               timeStyle:0]
```

Comment: is this available on the iPhone?  doesn't appear to be in the iPhone-specific NSDateFormatter docs.

Comment: timeStyle should be set to kCFDateFormatterNoStyle.  It happens to be 0 but you really shouldn't hardcode constants when there is a named constant provided.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to send setTimeStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle to the dateFormatter.  That sets the dateFormatter so that it will only format the date and not output the time:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[dateFormatter setLocale: [NSLocale currentLocale]];    
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle]; // or whichever style...
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle];   
NSString* dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
```

This gives me the following output:

```
12/18/09
```

Comment: May i get time without date in the same manner? if yes then it is not working for me. When i get time in NSDate then my object remains nil

Comment: It should work.  Post your code with a new question if you can't get it working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721553/get-time-from-nsdate-returns-nil/12721934#12721934